# Shiny - how to display dataframe?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working with Shiny and I try to display a dataframe as table in the shiny app. My data came from online website and I got them by using API:

```
make_house_representative_for_state <- function(state = "WA") {
  base_uri <- "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/"
  endpoint <- paste0(base_uri, "house/", state, "/current.json")
  response <- GET(endpoint, add_headers("X-API-Key" = ProPublica_KEY)) 
  df <- content(response, "text")
  dt <- fromJSON(df)
  output <- dt$results
  return(output)
}
```

API website: https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/

I put the above code in another R file and source it in my shiny R file.

```
source("source/propublica.R")

state_representatives <- make_house_representative_for_state()

ui <- fluidPage(

    theme = shinytheme("united"),

    titlePanel("Congressinal Member Information"),

    tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs", id = "nav_bar",

        tabPanel("State Rrepresentatives",
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         selectInput("selected_state",
                                     label = h3("Select A State"),
                                     choices = c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA",
                                                 "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA",
                                                 "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA",
                                                 "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
                                                 "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO",
                                                 "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ",
                                                 "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH",
                                                 "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC",
                                                 "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT",
                                                 "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"),
                                     selected = "WA"
                         )
                     ),

                     mainPanel(
                         tableOutput("state_representatives")
                     )
                 )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$state_representatives <- renderUI({
        state_choose <- input$selected_state
        state_name <- query_to_state_name(state_choose)
        state <- make_house_representative_for_state(state_name)
        return(state)
        # table <- summary_info(state)
    })

}
```

```
query_to_state_name <- function(query) {
  t <- paste0("\"", query, "\"")
  return(t)
}
```

The shiny app did run but no matter which state I click on it just shows nothing. When I tried to change "state_name" to "WA"(the default value in the API function), the shiny told me:

> Warning: Error in writeImpl: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector

I really cannot figure out why. I even need to do more on this data frame in shiny but even the most basic one I cannot solve.

Answer (score 0):

In the future when posting, please provide the following:

- a fully reproducible example, meaning: start to finish code (you are missing `shinyapp(ui, server)`), data in the code (you didn't provide the API key so your code can't be run), and all the library's that you used (I got on error on `shinythemes` because I don't have the package downloaded (or know what package it comes from)

As for your issue, use `renderTable` instead of `renderUI`. Each render/output are a pair and `renderUI` doesn't go with `tableOutput`.

If you are new to Shiny, there are some great tutorials online about how the server and UI can interact with each other ([Example](https://bookdown.org/weicheng/shinyTutorial/server.html)).